# Creating two dimensional array from mysql records in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, indexed

I have the following code:

```
while($row12 = mysql_fetch_array($result12)) {
    $position = $row12['position'];
    $tot[$k] = $row12['total'];
    $k++;
}

$arr = arsort($tot);

for($x = 0; $x < $k; $x++) {
    echo $tot[$x]."<br>";
}
```

I have been able to create the array of the totals from the database records but need to sort the values in descending order.

For example, before sorting:

> - 107
> - 563
> - 109
> - 246
> - 897

and after sorting:

> - 897
> - 563
> - 246
> - 109
> - 107

Comment: you can sort the values in your sql query .. I think thats much faster then in php. http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php here you can read about sorting with php functuons... So you do not have to implement youreown sorting function

Comment: i knew about this but it cannot give a solution to the problem as i av tried it

Comment: remove bad English, clearly show input-output and then code tired

Comment: code formatting only worked at the start of the content

Answer (score 0):

[arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) maintains array keys, so if you begin with

```
0 => 100
1 => 50
2 => 75
3 => 25
```

You will end up with

```
0 => 100
2 => 75
1 => 50
3 => 25
```

Which - on the surface - seems like what you want. The problem is that you're then looping through these and displaying them in the **key order** 0, 1, 2, 3 in your `for($x = 0; $x < $k; $x++)` loop.

One solution to this would be to use `foreach` instead:

```
foreach ($tot as $number_to_display) {
    echo $number_to_display . "<br>";
}
```

which will loop through them in the **array order** rather than iterating through keys sequentially as you tried.

The better solution, as has been commented, would be to use a sort condition in your SQL, something like:

```
ORDER BY total DESC
```